# modal em cima de outro modal sem aceitar o atalho um do outro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tenho um modal, que abre outro modal, até ai tudo bem, coloquei uma atalho o ctrl+alt+c para cancelar, até ai tudo bem, só que eu quero que quando eu abrir o segundo modal, e click no atalho somente ele feche e nao os dois, é posivel???

esse é o meu js

```
    $(document)
        .on(
                'keydown',
                function(e) {

                    if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey
                            && e.which === 67) {
                        document.getElementById(
                                "btnCancelar").click();

                    }
if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey
                        && e.which === 67) {
                    document.getElementById(
                            "btnCancelar1").click();

                }
    });
```

e com isso so coloco o id no meu html.
se alguem poder me ajudar??

cancelar do modal 1

```
<button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="limparCampos();" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelar">Cancelar</button>
```

cancelar do modal 2

```
<button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelar1">cancelar</button>
```

Comment: como está o código do **btnCancelar**

Comment: esse é do primeiro modal 
<button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="limparCampos();" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelar">Cancelar</button>

e esse e do segundo modal
<button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelar1">cancelar</button>

Comment: e sim tem outro funcao  if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey
      && e.which === 67) {
     document.getElementById(
       "btnCancelar1").click();

    }
para o segundo botao mais o atalho e o mesmo

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Modal dentro de modal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28144/modal-dentro-de-modal)

Comment: Seu botão tem o atributo `data-dismiss="modal"`, que irá fechar todas as modais abertas. Se quiser fechar apenas uma deverá implementar um código que faça isso.. a segunda modal pode por exemplo não term o `data-dismiss` e chamar uma function que execute algo como `$('#idDaSegundaModal').modal('hide')`

Comment: mesmo que fazer isso, e o atalho ctrl+alt+c ser igual pros dois, que no caso é assim que preciso, ele vai fechar os dois, ja tinha tentado isso, que uma outra vez em outros casos ja tinha me acontecido e esse cod me ajudou mais agora nao sei o q fazer pois sendo no js com id ou class ou qualquer outra coisa, se eles tiver a mesma função eles vao continuar fechando junto.